# Sorting dates by week and calculate sum using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I have a group of array values with 'Working_date' and  'Working_hours' as given below. These dates can be any dates but most probably they will be consecutive dates. So, I want to calculate the total working hours of each week based, on those dates. I am using NodeJs and moment.Js.Please help me to get this Expected output using Nodejs

Current Data :

```
 { Working_date: '2021-12-20', Working_hours: '1' }
 { Working_date: '2021-12-21', Working_hours: '2' }
 { Working_date: '2021-12-22', Working_hours: '2' }
 { Working_date: '2021-12-25', Working_hours: '5' }
 { Working_date: '2021-12-23', Working_hours: '4' }
 { Working_date: '2021-12-24', Working_hours: '2' }
```

Expected data:

```
 {

   Working_Startdate:'2021-12-20',
   Working_Enddate :'2021-12-24',
   TotalWorking_hours:16
   
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS solution:

```js
const data = [
    { Working_date: "2021-12-21", Working_hours: "2" },
    { Working_date: "2021-12-20", Working_hours: "1" },
    { Working_date: "2021-12-22", Working_hours: "2" },
    { Working_date: "2021-12-25", Working_hours: "5" },
    { Working_date: "2021-12-23", Working_hours: "4" },
    { Working_date: "2021-12-24", Working_hours: "2" },
];

const result = {
    Working_Startdate: data[0].Working_date,
    Working_Enddate: data[0].Working_date,
    TotalWorking_hours: 0,
};

data.forEach((e) => {
    const date = new Date(e.Working_date);
    if (date < new Date(result.Working_Startdate)) result.Working_Startdate = e.Working_date;
    if (date > new Date(result.Working_Enddate)) result.Working_Enddate = e.Working_date;

    result.TotalWorking_hours += Number(e.Working_hours);
});

console.log(result);
```

Logs the result object:

```
{
  Working_Startdate: '2021-12-20',
  Working_Enddate: '2021-12-25',
  TotalWorking_hours: 16
}
```